# How to add trigger to move file to azure blob from azure file share when a file uploaded to azure file share?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-files

The requirement is to move the files from azure file share to azure blob when user is uploading a file to azure file share.
I have gone through the link below:-
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/20324680-add-trigger-for-azure-file-storage

What I found out till now is trigger mechanism is not supported on azure file share like we can do on azure blob.So How I can achieve the same functionality on azure file share.
Basically i want a trigger on azure file share so that when file is uploaded i should able to execute my custom logic written in c# to process the file and upload to blob.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned the functionality is not yet offered as a connector, however, since you have written your custom logic in C#, you can use Azure Functions, which allows you to run custom code and will be used as if it was a logic app instance.  you can get the idea from:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions

I will also Upvote your feedback and will discuss the status with the internal teams as well.

Comment: I have used webjob with timer trigger to look to the file share in a interval of 2 minutes and when file receives it will move to container.But this is not that much feasible because each time it will trigger our code and unnecessary processing.In stead of this if there is direct file trigger on file share it will be very feasible

Comment: I did some testing, unfortunately it's not yet supported. It works for local drives on the VM but not on the file share itself using Logic App

Comment: yeah,this feature should be supported for better support for data movement